# sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() not working even though have contrib installed

Tags: opencv, python-3.5

So I am trying to use:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

and it is coming up with this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) 
This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake 
option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'
```

I am using `Python 3.5.0` and `opencv(3.4.3)` and I am just using idle. This occured after I tried to install TensorFlow and I have tried looking around and have installed opencv-contrib-python but I am still getting the same error. Thank you in advance and I apologise if I have not included enough info

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that SIRF and SURF are [no longer available in opencv > 3.4.2.16](https://github.com/DynaSlum/satsense/issues/13). I chose an older opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python versions and solved this problem. Here is the [history version](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history) about opencv-python, and I use the following code :

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

**Edit**

For Anaconda User just this instead of pip

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

this will install cv2 3.4.1 and everything you need to run SIFT

Comment: This is not working with Python 3.7. I tried with version 3.4.2.16, and I am getting DLL not found error. Base OpenCV is working with version 3.4.5.20

Comment: @NithishV did you find solution fot that? im using v3.7 and having this issue.

Comment: @DragonKnight, I am able to get it working with opencv-contrib-python version 3.4.5.20 only.
Install it using "pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20"

Comment: Quite tricky solution! Seemingly, it only works with a particular version! For the 3.4.2.16 version, I guess the OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE is turned on; when I install other version like 4.1.x.x, it will report a error like `OpenCV(4.1.0) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'`

Comment: OpenCV stopped including non-free/patented algorithms like SIFT and SURF as of v3.4.3. So either stick with v3.4.2.17, or compile the latest version from source if you need it.

Comment: Why is this the solution? I don' get python, it's weird.

Comment: It is one of the working solutions (for both python terminal and anaconda environment, both works) I found in the internet. It is Nov 2019, and this still works. Thank you for the simple solution.

Comment: I managed to install the [non conda] solution on Python 3.5, but not on 3.8. seems to work fine.

Comment: Works with python 3.6.9.

Comment: Not worked for me in Google Colab .it says python version 3.4.2.16 is not available

Comment: ```pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16``` doesn't work. "This release has been yanked" says in OpenCV version history, and videos/articles on how to build from source? Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Why downgrading the whole module when you can get the same feature by simply doing `sift = cv2.SIFT_create()` ?

Answer (score 19):

Since SIFT patent expired, SIFT has been moved to the main repo.

To use SIFT in Opencv, You should use

```
cv2.SIFT_create()
```

instead of

```
cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

`xfeatures2d` only exists in the contrib package, but sift is part of the main package now.

[This link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736) will be helpful.

Comment: The SIFT patent expired 6th March, 2020. https://patents.google.com/patent/US6711293

Answer (score 13):

Edit: The `opencv-contrib-python-nonfree` was removed from pypi.

<strike>**On Linux/ MacOS**, I've found a better solution! To access nonfree detectors use:
`pip install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree`</strike>

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python-nonfree (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python-nonfree

Comment: @Gulzar, I had this issue too. Possible reasons are: 1. Your OS is Windows; 2. You are using Python 3.8. According to this page: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python-nonfree/ Windows support is canceled and python 3.8 is not supported (possibly yet). I didn't found any solution to this problem, but on my other computers (Linux and MacOS), everything is fine.

Comment: @I.R. What Python version do you use?

Comment: @RoiMulia, I use Python 3.6

Answer (score 7):

It may be due to a mismatch of opencv version and opencv-contrib version.
If you installed opencv from the source using CMake, and the source version is different from the version of opencv-contrib-python, uninstall the current opencv-contrib-python and do `pip install opencv-contrib-python==<version of the source>.X` or an another compatible version.
One version setup that I have running is opencv source (3.2), opencv-python (3.4.0.14) and opencv-contrib-python (3.4.2.17)

Comment: The request for info should make into the comments section of the question. You could edit  your answer and leave just the workaround/solution.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Both my opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python version is 3.4.3.18. I assume these would be compatible?

Comment: I am guessing you installed them with `pip install`. Have you done another opencv installation, more specifically have you also installed opencv from the source ? If yes, what is the version of the sources ? 
I have installed the same version of `opencv-python, opencv-contrib-python` as you but with my 3.2 source installation and I get the same error msg. I would say an easy and lazy hack would be to uninstall opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python and reinstall with the same versions as me and give it a try.

Comment: still giving me this error :error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1210: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'create'

Comment: According to the error msg, you are using opencv-python==4.2.0
Did you also install `opencv-contrib-python` by running `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0`?

Answer (score 2):

I've been into this problem for many hours and finally I've solved it, and I'll share with you (and for any body else) how to solve it.

**Here are the steps:**

1- Download [CMAKE](https://cmake.org/download/) from the official website.

2- Download [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

3- Download [OpenCV Sources.zip](https://opencv.org/releases/) files.

4- Download [OpenCV-contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/4.7.0) from github.

---

- First, we'll create a directory and name it 'OpenCV', this directory will contain the 'opencv-x.x.x' and 'opencv_contrib-x.x.x' downloaded extracted files.
- We'll also create a 'build' directory that will contain the new OpenCV build files.

[image]

---

- The next step is to run the CMake (cmake-gui) app. [image]

---

- You should then

  1. locate the 'opencv-x.x.x' extracted folder in the directory we created 'OpenCV'.
  2. do the same for the 'build' folder.

[image]

- After doing that, click on 'Configure'

[image]

---

- A popup window should appear, choose the suitable configurations
  [image]
- Wait for the progress bar to finish.

---

- Check the OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE, then click 'Configure' again and wait for the progress bar.

[image]

---

- After it is done loading, click 'Generate', right next to 'Configure' button.
- Congrats, you've done the first steps!

---

- Okay, close the CMAKE (cmake-gui) app and go to the 'build' directory we created.
- locate 'OpenCV.sln' and run it using Visual Studio.
- Change vs build mode from 'Debug' to 'Release'.
- On the right 'Solution Explorer' menu, locate 'CMakeTargets' >> 'ALL_BUILD', right click it and select 'Build'
- Wait for it to build (it may take 5+ minutes)
- Again, on the right 'Solution Explorer' menu, locate 'CMakeTargets' >> 'INSTALL', right click it and select 'Build'

[image]

[image]

- After it finishes loading, you can then use it, that's all!

**Extra:**

- You can freely uninstall any pre-installations of 'opencv-python' and 'opencv-contrib-python' via the the pip

```
    pip uninstall opencv-python
    pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

- Reboot your device.
- Test OpenCV. Open a terminal and type

```
    $ python
    >>> import cv2
    >>> cv2.__version__
```

Hope this helps, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenCV version 4.7 and this works for me:

```
cv2.SIFT_create()
```

the `xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` method was removed because of some patent issues and is available in the short form as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if python version is latest.

> pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46