# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d' (OpenCV 4.1.2)

Tags: python, opencv

```
sift  = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()             

AttributeError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-11572687581a> in <module>()

      8 gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      9 #create sift object
---> 10 sift  = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
     11 #calculate keypoints and their orientation
     12 keypoints,descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)
```

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Answer (score 3):

It looks like sift and surf have been depreciated.

[sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() not working even though have contrib installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal)

That thread has a similar question and the selected answer is this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52514095/11013286

Answer (score 1):

i may be wrong but i think `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` only works in the old version