# Can't use SIFT in Python OpenCV v4.20

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, sift

I am using OpenCV v4.20 and PyCharm IDE. I want to use SIFT algorithm. But I get  this error. I looked for solutions of this error on the internet but none of them did help me. Do you know the solution of this error? (With pip I can install at least 3.4.2.16 version of OpenCV)

Here is my error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/features/featuredetect.py", line 7, in 
> sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp:1210: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create'

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread("the_book_thief.jpg")
gray_image = cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()
keyPoints = sift.detect(image,None)

output = cv.drawKeypoints(image,keyPoints,None)

cv.imshow("FEATURES DETECTED",output)
cv.imshow("NORMAL",image)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the error message is quite self-explaining, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT\_create() not working even though have contrib installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal)

Answer (score 15):

[SIFT's patent has expired](https://www.haikutechcenter.com/2020/07/patent-expired-on-sift.html) in last July. in versions > 4.4, the detector init command has changed to `cv2.SIFT_create()`.
If you're not using opencv's GUI, It's recommended to install the headless version: `pip install opencv-python-headless`

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2021. I had issues with `pip install opencv-python-headless`, but I was able to install `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and run sift as `cv2.SIFT_create()` without a problem.

Comment: As of January 2022, this is not correct anymore: it must have been moved once more.

Comment: @rikyeah please elaborate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11344054/nisan-chhetri 's answer below works for me, on a blank colab notebook

Comment: it's not a matter of date, it's a matter of opencv version. and for ver >4.4 this is correct one.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, according to this Github issue, [SIFT no longer available in opencv > 3.4.2](https://github.com/DynaSlum/satsense/issues/13). Since you're using OpenCV v4.2.0, it's not included even if you have installed `pip install opencv-contrib-python` as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/cant-use-surf-sift-in-opencv). A work around is to downgrade to any previous OpenCV version that includes SIFT (I believe any version below `3.4.3`). I've been successful when downgrading to `v3.4.2.16`.

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
```

---

Using your code with `v3.4.2.16`, SIFT seems to work

[image]

Comment: I did what you recommend.But still i am getting this error

Comment: worked for me,try these .. 
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17
, pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17

Comment: seems it is fixed for version 4.5.1

Comment: @EladMaimoni - It's not working for me in 4.5.1 or 4.5.5...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue previously. I had tried all methods but finally a very simple method work for me which has already answered by many. However, there is a little change in my approach.

1. ***Step 1:***

   Uninstall the previously install opencv library

   `pip uninstall opencv-python`
2. ***Step 2:***

   Install opencv contrib library due to copyright issue. Here, we are using version 3.4.2.17

   `pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17`

   [opencv contrib library installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWCK8.png)

   The above figure shows version `3.4.2.16` not found error. Hence, I tried with version `3.4.2.17`. If this version doesn't work, try other versions of 3.4.x.
3. ***Step 3:***

   Then  run the following

   `import cv2
   sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()`

That's all. It works for me. I hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after a lot of attempts, I tried installing opencv-contrib-python several times, but it worked just today. Just to be sure I installed both opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

And

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

The version that installed was 4.4.0.46 for both opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python. In case the later versions don't support it (A few of the previous versions didn't support SIFT, the one from a month ago, the latest opencv-contrib-python patch was released on Nov 2nd, 2020).

Answer (score -3):

The solution to your problem should be installing opencv-contrib-python-nonfree (available via pip).

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python-nonfree
```

As the error states SIFT is patented and therefore not included into OpenCV for license reasons. It's included in the nonfree part.

Comment: When ı run this command pip install opencv-python-nonfree
it says that "   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python-nonfree (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python-nonfree"