# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d' and module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

My python version = 3.7.4
cv2 version= 4.2.0

These are my version on python and open cv, Im trying to use SIFT function and I got the famous error module `cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT'`, so I tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and also `python -m pip install --user opencv-contrib-python`, and I changed  `detector=cv2.SIFT()` to `detector=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` and the error just changed to AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

I Tried with similar questions that I found, but are not working for me, I dont find a recent question, thats why Im opening this new because maybe as the version were different it could be the reason doesnt work for me

What else could I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT\_create() not working even though have contrib installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305578/sift-cv2-xfeatures2d-sift-create-not-working-even-though-have-contrib-instal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIFT and SURF are proprietary, patented algorithms.  You'd need to compile OpenCV and OpenCV-contrib from source, with non-free packages enabled, building the python libraries.  I wasn't able to get this working so I used pip to find an older version (3.4.2) that did not remove the non-free libraries.  I may have had to roll back python but I'm not sure.  I am using python 3.6.8

Comment: are you saying with Python Version = 3.6.8 and Opencv Version=3.4.2 , Did you get SIFT working on?

Comment: I haven't tried SIFT but I've gotten SURF working.  It's under the same restrictions.
I did a quick `import cv2` and `detector =cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` and have no errors.