# Python image processing: How do you align images that have been rotated and shifted?

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

Here I have some code that can vertically and horizontally shift images so that a specific feature can align (credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769222/15016884):

```
def cross_image(im1, im2):
    im1_gray = np.sum(im1.astype('float'), axis=2)
    im2_gray = np.sum(im2.astype('float'), axis=2)

    im1_gray -= np.mean(im1_gray)
    im2_gray -= np.mean(im2_gray)

   
    return signal.fftconvolve(im1_gray, im2_gray[::-1,::-1], mode='same')

corr_img_null = cross_image(cloud1,cloud1)
corr_img = cross_image(cloud1,cloud2)

y0, x0 = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr_img_null), corr_img_null.shape)
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr_img), corr_img.shape)
  
ver_shift = y0-y
hor_shift = x0-x

print('horizontally shifted', hor_shift)
print('vertically shifted', ver_shift)

#defining the bounds of the part of the images I'm actually analyzing
xstart = 100
xstop = 310
ystart = 50
ystop = 200

crop_cloud1 = cloud1[ystart:ystop, xstart:xstop]
crop_cloud2 = cloud2[ystart:ystop, xstart:xstop]
crop_cloud2_shift = cloud2[ystart+ver_shift:ystop+ver_shift, xstart+hor_shift:xstop+hor_shift]

plot_pos = plt.figure(5)
plt.title('image 1')
plt.imshow(crop_cloud1)

plot_pos = plt.figure(6)
plt.title('image 2')
plt.imshow(crop_cloud2)

plot_pos = plt.figure(7)
plt.title('Shifted image 2 to align with image 1')
plt.imshow(crop_cloud2_shift)
```

Here are the results:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: shifted image 2 to align with image 1]

Now, I want to work with the example shown below, where rotations in addition to translations will be needed to align the features in my image.

[image: bolt1]

[image: bolt2]

Here is my code for that: The idea is to convolve each possible configuration of image 2 for every angle from -45 to 45 (for my application, this angle is not likely to be exceeded) and find at which coordinates and rotation angle the convolution is maximized.

```
import cv2

def rotate(img, theta):
    (rows, cols) = img.shape[:2]

    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols / 2, rows / 2), theta, 1)
    res = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (cols, rows))
    return res

#testing all rotations of image 2
corr_bucket = []
for i in range(-45,45):
    rot_img = rotate(bolt2,i)
    corr_img = cross_image(bolt1,rot_img)
    corr_bucket.append(corr_img)
corr_arr = np.asarray(corr_bucket)


corr_img_null = cross_image(bolt1,bolt1)


y0, x0 = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr_img_null), corr_img_null.shape)
r_index, y1, x1 = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(corr_arr), corr_arr.shape)

r = -45+r_index
ver_shift = y0-y
hor_shift = x0-x
ver_shift_r = y0-y1
hor_shift_r = x0-x1

#What parts of the image do you want to analyze
xstart = 200
xstop = 300
ystart = 100
ystop = 200

crop_bolt1 = bolt1[ystart:ystop, xstart:xstop]
crop_bolt2 = bolt2[ystart:ystop, xstart:xstop]
rot_bolt2 = rotate(bolt2,r)
shift_rot_bolt2 = rot_bolt2[ystart+ver_shift_r:ystop+ver_shift_r, xstart+hor_shift_r:xstop+hor_shift_r]

plot_1 = plt.figure(9)
plt.title('image 1')
plt.imshow(crop_bolt1)

plot_2 = plt.figure(10)
plt.title('image 2')
plt.imshow(crop_bolt2)

plot_3 = plt.figure(11)
plt.title('Shifted and rotated image 2 to align with image 1')
plt.imshow(shift_rot_bolt2)
```

Unfortunately, from the very last line, I get the error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`. I'm kind of new to python so I don't really know what this means or why my approach isn't working. I have a feeling that my error is somewhere in unraveling corr_arr because the x, y and r values it returns I can already see, just by estimating, would not make the lightning bolts align. Any advice?

Comment: Search keyword: orthogonal procrustes algorithm

Comment: the normal approach would be to simplify the problem so you feed the problem lines of code a known input with a grip as to what the output should be then go into battle until the offending code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from feeding in the entire rotated image into scipy.signal.fftconvolve. Crop a part of image2 after rotating to use as a "probe image" (crop your unrotated image 1 in the same way), and the code I have written in my question works fine.